# How to resolve java.util.zip.ZipException duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using android studio. In my project i am try to compile two library's.

1. AWS.jar
2. Mp_library.jar

Both are .Jar files are using different GSON versions.
When i compile my project i am getting below error

Error:Execution failed for task ':cloudAndroid:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class

```
    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'mp_library', ext: 'aar')
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.6.jar')
}
```

Can you guys please help me. Thanks a lot.

---

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude one transitive dependency of GSON libraries either from AWS or from Mp_library.jar. Syntax is

```
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.6.jar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
```

Since you using gradle maybe it's better to refer to maven repository dependency, than to downloaded jar.

Answer (score 1):

This worked very well for me.In my case i was using Signalr Android SDK and retrofit whch both had gson dependencies i excluded them from the libraries and added gson to the project as a stand alone and my APK builds successfully and all network calls from both retrofit and SignalR return successfully

```
//compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'){
    transitive=true;
    exclude module: 'gson'
}
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'){
         transitive=true;
         exclude module: 'gson'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
  multiDexEnabled = true    
}
```